# Questions about executing loops with an ANTLR treewalker

Tags: c#, loops, antlr

I've read a few things about loops in ANTLR, but I still don't get how to actually built a treewalker for loops. So what I want to do is to parse and execute statements like these:

```
int a = 1
while(a < 3) {
    int c = 1
    a = a + 1
}
```

When I put this in my parser, the resulting AST looks like this:
[image: AST]

Now I want to create a treewalker which first checks if the while-condition is true, then executes the statements or if the statement isn't true, jumps to the statement after the while. Therefore, I guess I have to know how to get the index of the EOF in order to skip to it, but I have no idea how to do that.

What I tried out was the code sample on [this page](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/Tree-based+interpreters), but it seems that it doesn't work any more (you can see this in the comments below), and what also bothers me about this, is the fact that VARDEF and ASSIGN is executed before the while-loop is executed and I don't see how to change this.

So what I want to know is, do I have the right approach here, or is there a better way of doing this? Can you give me an example treewalker for my while-loop, I think that would be really helpful.

Here is my current try for a treewalker:

```
tree grammar SGLTreeWalker;

options {
    tokenVocab = SGL;
    language = 'CSharp2';
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

@namespace { SGL }

@header {
    using System.Collections.Generic;
}

@members{
    SGLActions action = new SGLActions();
}

compilationUnit
    :   mainStatement+ EOF
    ;

mainStatement
    :   statement
    ;   

statement
    :   variableDeclarationList // int a = 1, b = 2, c
    |   ^(ASSIGN variableAssignment) // a = 4
    |   whileLoop
    ;

/* Statements */

whileLoop
    :   ^('while' expression statement*)
    {
        int next = input.Index(); // index of node following WHILE
        input.Seek($expression.start.startIndex);
        Object condition = expression();
        while((Boolean) condition) {
            input.Seek($statement.start.startIndex);
            statement();
            input.Seek($expression.start.startIndex);
                condition = expression();
        }
        input.Seek(next);
    }
    ;

variableDeclarationList
    :   ^(VARDEF variableType variableName expression) {    
        action.NewLocalVariable($variableType.txt,$variableName.txt,$expression.txt); 
    }
    ;

// Only used for the first time declaration of a new variable
variableAssignment
    :   variableName expression? {
        action.AssignVariable($variableName.txt,$expression.txt);
    }
    ;

variableName returns [string txt]
    :   Identifier {$txt = $Identifier.text;}
    ;   

variableType returns [string txt]
    :   IntType {$txt = $IntType.text;}
    |   BooleanType {$txt = $BooleanType.text;}
    |   StringType {$txt = $StringType.text;}
    |   FloatType {$txt = $FloatType.text;}
    ;     

/* Expressions */

// start rule for all sorts of expressions
expression returns [string txt]
    :   ^('+' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.Add($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('-' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.Sub($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('*' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.Mult($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('/' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.Div($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('%' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.Remainder($a.txt,$b.txt); } 
    |   ^(NEGATE a=expression) { $txt = action.Mult($a.txt,"-1"); }
    |   ^('<' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.ConditionLess($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('<=' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.ConditionLessOrEqual($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('>' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.ConditionGreater($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('>=' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.ConditionGreaterOrEqual($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('!=' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.ConditionNotEqual($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('==' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.ConditionEqual($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('&&' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.ConnectiveAnd($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('||' a=expression b=expression) { $txt = action.ConnectiveOr($a.txt,$b.txt); }
    |   ^('?' a=expression b=expression c=expression) { $txt = action.ConditionBranch($a.txt,$b.txt,$c.txt); }
    |   Identifier { $txt = action.GetVariable($Identifier.text); }
    |   IntegerAtom { $txt = $IntegerAtom.text; }
    |   BooleanAtom { $txt = $BooleanAtom.text; }
    ;
```

Comment: I recently wrote a couple of blogs that shows how to interpret a small language including `for`- and `while` statements. Checkout the [first post here](http://bkiers.blogspot.com/2011/03/creating-your-own-programming-language.html).

Comment: I just found it yesterday by looking at your profile, and I must say that this is a very nice and structured way for creating a DSL, and it's helping me a lot. Thank you for your work.